# Is it natural to say “one of the paradise places”?

Tags: phrase-choice

Would a native English speaker say something like this?

> Vatican Garden is one of the paradise places.

or

> Vatican Garden is one of paradise places.

For my native language it seems quite odd.

Comment: It would be understood, but considered odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Collins English Dictionary, [paradise is a noun](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/paradise). This means that it cannot be used as an adjective to describe a second noun. So, this sentence would be:

> Vatican Garden is a place of paradise.

Or:

> Vatican Garden is a paradise.

It may also be used without an article (the/a/an) before it, but this is rarer.

> ...one of the world's natural paradises. <sub>(Quote from Collins)</sub>